# How to scan git repositories for Jenkins file and if found create a job in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I want to automate the creation of Jenkins pipeline. When I create a new repository or branch containing Jenkinsfile then it will create a new job in Jenkins and trigger it. Any one can help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using this plugin to Jenkins: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-branch-source-plugin

It automatically scans a GitHub organization and any repositories which have a Jenkinsfile will have a Jenkins job created and it will start to run.